# Best and efficient way to find non duplicate items on a list and save it on another list

Tags: performance, list, duplicates

```
Class encargo
Property idEncargo as int
Property listEncargoCollege As IList(Of encargoCollege)

Class encargoCollege
Property idEncargo as int
Property rate as Decimal
Property college as College

Class college
Property idCollege as int
Property name as String
Property serial as int
```

So I Have a list(Of Encargo) with **1000 Encargos**.
Each Encargo has **at least 50 EncargoCollege.**

Each college **is unique by his idCollege.**

**On a Encargo all encargoColleges must be differents** (differents idCollege)

What I need is iterate list(of Encargo) and for each different idCollege found on the list; show the sum of Tax and Sum of Rate.
Ex:

Encargo (idEncargo=1)

EncargoCollege (idCollege=55, rate=100);  EncargoCollege(idCollege=56, rate=200)

Encargo 2 (idEncargo=2)

EncargoCollege (idCollege=56, rate=500);  EncargoCollege(idCollege=57, rate=800); EncargoCollege(idCollege=58, rate=1200)

I have to show:

EncargoCollege 1(idCollege is 55; college.name is Paul; rate is 100)

EncargoCollege 2(idCollege is 56; college.name is Peter; rate is 700)

EncargoCollege 3(idCollege is 57; college.name is Mike; rate is 800)

EncargoCollege 4(idCollege is 58; college.name is Jack; rate is 1200)

**What is the best way on terms of speed and efficiency to achieve this?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, just wanted to know what programming language is this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not looking for a specific value or subset of the information in the data collection, nor have a way to short circuit the iterations I try to accomplish that task with a nested 'for' cycle, when you say:

> What I need is iterate list(of Encargo) and for each different idCollege found on the list; show the sum of Tax and Sum of Rate.

having in pseudocode something like:

```
  foreach (var e in Encargo)
  {
    decimal taxSum = 0, rateSum = 0;
    foreach (var eC in e.listEncargoCollege)
    {
      rateSum += eC.rate;
      taxSum += eC.Tax; //though I didn't see where the tax field was declared/defined.
    }
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("EncargoCollege {0}: rate Sum = {1} , tax Sum = {2} ", e.idEncargo, rateSum, taxSum));
  }
```

for the second part do not sumarize, just print the values inside the second foreach statement.

I didn't understood where duplicates could exist, specially at encargoCollege (the id makes them unique, doesn't it?), if that's not possible maybe this helps!